# Update deeply nested field with value from higher-level object in JQ

Tags: json, nested, jq, updates

Given the following input JSON:

```json
{
  "version": 2,
  "models": [
    {
      "name": "first_table",
      "tests": [
        {
          "dbt_utils.equal_rowcount": {
            "compare_model": null
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "second_table",
      "tests": [
        {
          "dbt_utils.equal_rowcount": {
            "compare_model": null
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

**How would I, using `jq`, replace the `null` (i.e., the value of `"compare_model"`) with the value from the `"name"` key?** Note that the key-value pairs in question here are not at the same level in the hierarchy: the former is nested in an object in an array, and it is this array that is at the same level as the latter.

For example, the output file should read:

```json
{
  "version": 2,
  "models": [
    {
      "name": "first_table",
      "tests": [
        {
          "dbt_utils.equal_rowcount": {
            "compare_model": "first_table"
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "second_table",
      "tests": [
        {
          "dbt_utils.equal_rowcount": {
            "compare_model": "second_table"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

FWIW, this is an intermediate step in some YAML (via `yq`, the Python wrapper variety of `jq` as opposed to the `go` variant) wrangling I'm doing on [DBT config files](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/model-properties).

(Bonus points if you can wrap the replacement text with parentheses and/or prefix it without breaking out of `jq`. :D If not, no worries -- this step I can do with another program.)

Needless to say, but your help is very much appreciated!

---

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That the fields are not at the same level doesn't really matter here.

```
.models[] |= (.tests[]."dbt_utils.equal_rowcount".compare_model = "(\(.name))")
```

<sup>[Online demo](https://jqplay.org/s/-HcdQGxFrl)</sup>

Comment: Wow, I knew I was on the right track with the |= operator. Thanks for the working demo!

Comment: Note to self for future reference while leveraging @peak's answer below: to concatenate data instead of replacing do `.models |= map(.name as $n | .tests |= map(."dbt_utils.equal_rowcount".compare_model = "(\(.compare_model):\($n))"))`

Answer (score 3):

The key to a simple solution is to use `|=`, e.g.

```
.models |= 
  map(.name as $name
      | (.tests[]."dbt_utils.equal_rowcount".compare_model =
         $name))
```

To wrap the replacement value in parentheses, just add them:

```
.models |= 
  map("(\(.name))" as $name
      | (.tests[]."dbt_utils.equal_rowcount".compare_model =
         $name))
```

If you want the replacement to be conditional on the existing value being `null`, you could perhaps (depending on the exact requirements) use `//=`.

### Using `//=` and `walk`

Here's another take on the problem:

```
.models
  |= map("(\(.name))" as $name
         | walk(if type=="object" and has("compare_model") 
                then .compare_model //= $name
                else . end))
```

Comment: Your point about conditionals is very interesting. I'm going to study this in more detail tomorrow.